# Manually typing code gives unexpected input error in Rstudio unless I copy paste the code

Tags: r

I am learning R programming and I have tried to reproduce code from several examples (typing it myslef into RStudio console) and sometimes mine would give an error for no apparent reason.

I found out that if I manually type the entire code in RStudio it gives me "rror: unexpected input in "first_line_of_code
If right after I copy exactly that same code from the console (pressing up arrow, selecting and copying) and then paste it in the same place, it works.

Why is that happening and how can I solve it?

Example:

```
h<- c()
for (i in 1:10) {
    h <- append (h,i^2)
}
h
```

Error is "rror: unexpected input in "h<- c()

---

Thanks for the replies.

The code I posted is just an example of the multiple codes that gave me an error when I type it, but works once I copy paste the same code that I typed.

I my main concern is to figure out why that happens and how to solve it since now every time I get an error I have to copy paste it just to be sure that I actually did something wrong.

Any idea about that?

Comment: works for me. Are you sure you didn't assign a personal function to `c()`? Look at `conflicts()`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be reproducible.. Anyway, I wonder what `h <- c()` should be good for? When I do that, `h` is `NULL`, `class(h)` is also `NULL`, `str(h)` is `NULL` .. I think you want to initialize it using something like `h <- vector("numeric", length = 10)` or `h <- numeric(10)`. And you could do what you do in the for loop with `h <- (1:10)^2`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to learn here?  There are much better ways of creating an object with no content, e.g.

`h <- vector('numeric')`

And if you want to "build" a vector, **always** start by creating an empty vector of desired length. There's a huge time penalty if you re-size it every time thru a loop.

What you **should** be doing,  I suspect, is:

```
h <- (1:10)^2
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the error you reported exactly, but I can get close to it...

It think it is because you're copying another symbol when you're copying across the code, such as a quotation mark. If you have a look at your console, when you enter the text the first time (with the erroneous " at the front), it gives you a `+` symbol where you type, instead of the usual `>`:

```
> "h<- c() 
+ for (i in 1:10) {
+     h <- append (h,i^2)
+ }
+ h
+
```

Then pressing the up arrow and running the same thing again actually closes the quote, and lets the whole thing run again, adding in the error.

```
+ "h<- c()
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"
"h"
> for (i in 1:10) {
+     h <- append (h,i^2)
+ }
> h
```

If it's not this, try copying each line across one at a time. This will tell you which line R is having an issue with. Hope that helps :)